# Unit testing methods which use global variables

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Lets say I have the following class structure:

```
private string GlobalVariable = "foo";

public void MainMethod()
{
    string bar = Baz();
}

public string Baz()
{
    return GlobalVariable + "qux";
}
```

I wish to carry out a unit test on `Baz()` using different values for `GlobalVariable`. However as `GlobalVariable` is simply called within the method, and not passed to it as a parameter, I cannot set this in my unit test method.

Therefore I've considered changing my structure to:

```
private string GlobalVariable = "foo";

public void MainMethod()
{
    string bar = Baz(GlobalVariable);
}

public string Baz(string globalVar)
{
    return globalVar + "qux";
}
```

This way I can now change the parameter value `globalVar` in my unit tests in order to check different outputs.

However, my first structure is more cleaner as I'm not unnecessarily passing variable values to methods as parameters.

Is there a way of getting the best of both worlds, without having to hinder my structure in order to run unit tests?

Comment: No... this is why static classes are difficult to test. As you have found.. global state doesn't test well.

Comment: Wait.. is this static? What defines "global" in your example?

Comment: I guess the question is how / why would your `GlobalVariable` change when being used in the real-world? If it doesn't then do you really need to test it? If it does change then by what mechanism and test that mechanism.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead No its not static, I mean global as in within the scope of the class. But this is just an example, global could a static variable scoped within the namespace

Comment: @Belogix In the real world `GlobalVariable` is an application/config setting

Comment: You should definitely read [Misco's blog(s)](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-brittle-global-state-singletons/$). He explains very well all the problems and pitfalls using global variables not only when testing but also about "understanding" the code.

Comment: Is the `GlobalVariable` immutable?

Comment: @DavinTryon Yes, `GlobalVariable` in my example, is actually an application setting

Comment: @DavinTryon That's correct. Apologies for any mistakes in the code, I wrote this quickly in StackOverflow, no time for unit testing ;)

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers I get a 404 with that link, but I'm interested in reading about the pitfalls of global variables. Is there perhaps another link?

Comment: Why are you testing more than one method anyway?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Are you suggesting I should only be testing the `MainMethod` method? Please remember this is just a simple example I've made to express the issue I have with global variables.

Comment: @Curt - Copied to much. Following link should work -http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-brittle-global-state-singletons/

Comment: and check out the [Google Clean Code talks](http://www.google.be/search?hl=nl&q=clean+code+talks+misko+hevery&sourceid=ie8&rls=com.microsoft:nl-be:IE-SearchBox&ie=&oe=) (also from Misco)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would be tempted to have a separate overloaded method, then I could have one with the parameter and one without...

```
public string Baz()
{
    return Baz(GlobalVariable);
}

public string Baz(string globalVar)
{
    return globalVar + "qux";
}
```

The benefit here is that you still have your parameter-less method which can be called from code without you having to worry about specifying the value each time, but then you have the overload for testing and also in the event you do ever need to use a different value.

Although you still cannot test the first method using different values, I think it would be safe to assume testing the second function only would be enough.

---

Or, if you are using C# 4.0 you could use [optional parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) instead:

```
public string Baz(string globalVar = null)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(globalVar))
        globalVar = GlobalVariable;
    return globalVar + "qux";
}
```

Comment: Overloading sounds like a good idea here, it will give me the benefits of both. However I'll have to ensure this is documented well, or else seeing overloaded methods with no visible use in the class could be confusing for other developers! Is this standard practice for this scenario? It seems like this would be a common issue with unit testing, but I can't find any references to previous solutions.

Comment: Well, "standard practice" for me is often "whatever I feel like doing". If it is something I have never needed to overcome before I just go for what feels like it will work well. If I then get 6 months down the line and find any problems with it, then it is a lesson learned for the next time I need to solve the same problem where I can try a different approach. I have certainly used this method before for when I want default parameters, but also allow for the occasional override, and I haven't experienced anything that would give me reason to avoid using it again in the future.

Comment: I've implemented this solution. I've changed my mind about this causing confusion, I think passing the value as a parameter makes the method more of a "unit/component" which doesn't rely on outsider variables.

Answer (score 2):

If the global variable is immutable (like and application setting), I would not use an overload.  Instead I would access the application setting in the testing code.  So, I would leave it like this:

```
public string Baz()
{
    return ApplicationSetting.GlobalVariable + "qux";
}
```

then in the test I would do something like this:

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
     string expected = ApplicationSetting.GlobalVariable + "qux";
     Assert.AreEqual(expected, Baz());
}
```

Then both the code under test and the test itself are using the same application setting source.  This means that the source can change, but the test won't break.  Hope this helps.